# Добавления Appscentrum в html

Tags: html, node.js

Всем привет!
Хочу добавить [appscentrum](https://appscentrum.com/instructions#media-direct) в html, для добавления они используют библиотеку VkBridge, а она в свою очередь есть только для NodeJs. Может кто сталкивался с похожей проблемой и знает решение. Буду рад любому совету!

Answer (score 2):

Согласно описанию [пакета](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vkontakte/vk-bridge), VkBridge доступен и для браузера:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@vkontakte/vk-bridge/dist/browser.min.js"></script>

<script>
  // Sends event to client
  vkBridge.send('VKWebAppInit');
</script>
```